# How to generate video thumbnail from input file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, video

How to draw an image thumbnail of a video from input file? This is what i've tried so far

```js
let targetInput = document.getElementById('video-input');

targetInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    let videoMetaData = (file) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let video = document.createElement('video');
            
            // video.preload = 'metadata';

            video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
                // console.log(video.src)
                
                resolve({
                    video: video,
                    duration: Math.round(video.duration * 1000),
                    height: video.videoHeight,
                    width: video.videoWidth
                })
            }

            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        })
    }

    videoMetaData(e.target.files[0]).then(function(value) {
        let videoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        videoCanvas.height = value.height;
        videoCanvas.width = value.width;
        videoCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(value.video, 0, 0)
        var snapshot = videoCanvas.toDataURL();

        console.log(snapshot)
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="video-input" />
```

This code is working. You can see the result on your browser console, but why the image URI result was blank?

Comment: @Tân on your browser console `console.log(snapshot)`

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of this: You are missing to append the `<video>` element to the body after creating: `document.createElement('video');`

You just need to append it for testing:

```
// after this line
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

// try this...
video.controls = 'controls';            
document.body.appendChild(video);
```

---

Update:

```js
let targetInput = document.getElementById('video-input');

targetInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    let videoMetaData = (file) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let video = document.createElement('video');
            
            // video.preload = 'metadata';

            video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
                resolve({
                    video: video,
                    duration: Math.round(video.duration * 1000),
                    height: video.videoHeight,
                    width: video.videoWidth
                });
            });


            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            document.body.appendChild(video);
            
            video.play();
        })
    }

    videoMetaData(this.files[0]).then(function(value) {
        let videoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        videoCanvas.height = value.height;
        videoCanvas.width = value.width;
        videoCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(value.video, 0, 0);
        var snapshot = videoCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        var img = new Image();
        
        img.onload = function () {
          document.body.appendChild(this);
        };
        
        img.src = snapshot;
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="video-input" />
```

Comment: did you tried this? the image result is still blank

Comment: @Myrealname Yes, really. I've updated my answer with your example. After appending, nothing is blank more.

Comment: i mean not to showing the video, but the image for example `<img src='this is the uri result as the video thumbnail' />`

Comment: @Myrealname Oh, sorry. I've updated my answer. I'm drunk for a party just now. You can use `canplay` event instead of `loadeddata` event. To caugh the event `canplay`, you need to play the video.

Comment: @Myrealname Because I don't see any `<img>` tag in your question, so in this example, I've added new image to the body. `snapshot` is not blank anymore.

Comment: i have a question, is it imposible without showing the video into the html?

Comment: @Myrealname Yes. After getting the thumbnail, you can remove the video via `value.video.parentElement.removeChild(value.video);`. While generating thumbnail, if you want to pause the video, you can try `video.pause()` inside the event.

Comment: @Myrealname Or you can hide it with css `display: none`.